# Pass parameter from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity that calls to a web service and I want to pass these result to a fragment. Obviously the web service is invoked by an AsyncTask, so the fragment is loaded before getting result.

How can I pass this paramteter from activity's AsyncTask to fragment when is received?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a method inside your Fragment and call it when needed. For bidirectional communication between an Activity and a Fragment see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

Set bundle in your fragment.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("id",value);    
Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

In your fragment get the bundle as

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String s = b.getInt("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the AsyncTask into the fragment.

But if you wish to keep your current set up, you should save the Fragment reference when you initialize it, and create a public function in the fragment that takes the new data as a parameter.

So the activity code could look like this:

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

and then you could call:

```
fragment.updateData(myNewData);
```

Just make sure to do the appropriate null-checks, just to be safe.